How do you make a successful transaction from a MySQL database using a restful API
I am working on a banking application and want to simply withdraw from my account. I have written the code for the API I'll be using to assist me in making the transaction from a MySQL table. After testing the API, all the error-handling messages I have included are working as expected but I have been unable to successfully withdraw. If you can, kindly help me resolve this error. Thanks in advance.
At first, I isolated the class for withdrawals and ran the code separate from the other classes and functions that I have. I ran into the same problem. I then turned to some documentation from online sites to find a possible solution but I haven't found a suitable solution.
If I attempt to withdraw by providing the JSON payload with the valid account number and an amount that is less than the amount in my database, I'll get a response that the withdrawal is unsuccessful.
class Withdraw(Resource):
    
    def post(self):
        connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', database='databaseName')
        cursor = connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        data = request.json
        account_number = data['account_number']
        amount = data['amount']
        sql= 'select * from accountTable where account_number = %s'

        cursor.execute(sql, (account_number))
        amount_in_account = cursor.fetchone()
        try:
            if (cursor.rowcount == 1):
                if amount_in_account['balance'] <= amount:
                    return jsonify({"message": "Insufficient funds"})
                elif (amount_in_account['balance'] > amount):
                    updated_balance = amount_in_account['balance'] - amount
                    sql1 = 'update accountTable set balance = %s where account_number = %s'
                    cursor.execute(sql1, (updated_balance, account_number))
                    connection.commit()
                    sql2 = 'insert into transactionsTable (account_number, balance) values(%s, %s)'
                    cursor.execute(sql2, (account_number, amount_in_account['balance']))
                    connection.commit()
                    return jsonify({"message": "Withdrawal successful"})
            else:
                return jsonify({"message": "Account number does not exist"})
        except:
            if connection:
                connection.rollback()
            return jsonify({"message": "Withdrawal unsuccessful"})
        finally:
            if connection:
                connection.close()


what error u r getting

I get this message. {"message": "Withdrawal unsuccessful"}

use debugger and see at what step you are failing

I've tried to do so, but the response that I'm receiving isn't that helpful. I tried running the code without saving the transaction in the transactions table, and it worked. However, I prefer saving the transaction details in that given database.
